# Conditionally render attributes in React / Formik

Tags: reactjs, jsx, formik

I need to display the label attribute on an Formik Input only when the screensize is below a certain screensize. To do that, I need to conditionally render the label attribute.

Is there a more elegant (dry?) way to do it instead of just this:

```
if (smallScreen) {
    <Input
        label="Unit"
        type="text"
        name="unit"
        value={values.unit}
    />  
} else {
    <Input
        type="text"
        name="unit"
        value={values.unit}
    />
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set a react prop to `null`, react will ignore it:

```
    <Input
        label={smallScreen ? "Unit" : null}
        type="text"
        name="unit"
        value={values.unit}
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const label =smallScreen? { label : "Unit"} : null

<Input

        type={smallScreen? Unit }
        name="unit"
        value={values.unit}
        {...label}
    />
```